# Libgit2 git_blob vs memory

Tags: c, libgit2

It's not clear to me at which point does the content of a blob actually get loaded into memory.

The logic that I have in my code is the following:

```
git_blob_lookup(&blob_, repo_, oid)

if (git_blob_rawsize(blob_) < LIMIT)
  git_blob_rawcontent(blob_)
```

This is to prevent DOSing myself by reading big files. But from the API description I'm not quite sure if this is actually preventing the blob from being loaded into memory.

If no, is there an API call that would give me the size of a blob, without loading it into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for `git_blob_rawcontent` from libgit2's "src/blob.c" is as follows:

```
const void *git_blob_rawcontent(const git_blob *blob)
{
        assert(blob);
        if (blob->raw)
                return blob->data.raw.data;
        else
                return git_odb_object_data(blob->data.odb);
}
```

And the source for `git_odb_object_data` from "src/odb.c" is as follows:

```
const void *git_odb_object_data(git_odb_object *object)
{
        return object->buffer;
}
```

So `git_block_rawcontent` is not loading any data from the repo, it is just returning a pointer to data that has already been loaded and is being pointed to by either `blob->data.raw.data` or `blob->data.odb->buffer`.  The loading (possibly from a cache of already loaded objects) is done by the `git_blob_lookup` call.

---

The only method I can find to read the size without having to load the entire blob (or other object type) is to call `git_odb_read_header`, but note the documentation for `git_odb_read_header` that says:

> Note that most backends do not support reading only the header of an object, so the whole object will be read and then the header will be returned.

Nevertheless, if you want to try it, the prototype is as follows:

```
int get_odb_read_header(size_t *len_out, git_object_t *type_out, git_odb *db, const git_oid *id);
```

If the OID is found in the ODB (return value is 0 if found, `GIT_ENOTFOUND` if not found), the object's length and type will be returned via `len_out` and `type_out`. The type value for a blob is `GIT_OBJECT_BLOB`.

To call `get_odb_read_header`, you need an ODB pointer for the repository. That can be obtained by calling `git_repository_odb` which has a prototype as follows:

```
int git_repository_odb(git_odb **out, git_repository *repo);
```

`git_repository_odb` returns 0 on success or an error code on failure. If it returned successfully, the ODB should be freed when it is no longer required by calling `git_odb_free` which has a prototype as follows:

```
void git_odb_free(git_odb *db);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read the entirety of the blob's content into memory.

If you want more information about the blob *before* you read it, you'll need to talk to the object database directly.

In particular, calling [`git_odb_read_header`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/odb.h#L150) will read only the object's metadata, so the type of object (blob/tree/commit) and the size of the object.  (This is the size that will be returned by `git_blob_rawsize`.)